# Reaction Roles with Custom emojis

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having issues with getting reaction roles to work with custom emojis. If I use discord emojis, it embeds the message, creates the reactions and applies the role when the reaction is clicked.

However, if I use a custom emoji, it embeds the message and creates the correct reactions, however it does not provide the role when the emoji is clicked.

I've used the same coding when swapping between discord and custom emojis, the only changes made were the emoji IDs.

The full code I'm using is:

```js
const { MessageReaction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "reactionrole",
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = "764347631081881660";
        const sheRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "She/Her");
        const heRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "He/Him");
        const theyRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "They/Them");

        const sheEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("805419160497946634");
        const heEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("795488864721829928");
        const theyEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("795871326446419968");

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#e42643")
            .setTitle("Self Assignable Roles")
            .setDescription(
                "To Join one of our self-assignable roles, click/tap the reaction with the appropriate emoji for that role. (Note that this is purely for fun and for helpful tags & inclusivity.) By doing this we are hoping to better assist everyone in how they can address others. This also adds helpful knowledge of when someone may be on for trades, events etc.This is also not mandatory but highly recommended. isaheart \n\n" +
                    `List of corresponding emojis & roles:\n\n` +
                    `Identify yourself:\n` +
                    `:judy: She/Her\n` +
                    `:raymond: He/Him\n` +
                    `:zucker: They/Them\n\n` +
                    `Removing your reaction will also remove the role from yourself. You can have multiple roles so go ahead and choose one from each category ^^If you have any questions please feel free to reach out to any of our Admin`
            );

        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(sheEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(heEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(theyEmoji);

        client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === sheEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(sheRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === heEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(heRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === theyEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(theyRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });

        client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === sheEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(sheRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === heEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(heRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === theyEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(theyRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    },
};
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`Emoji#name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji?scrollTo=name) for custom emojis and default ones. The problem with this is that custom emoji's do not have the [`Emoji#name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji?scrollTo=name) property ( same goes for default emojis, they do not have a [`Emoji#id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji?scrollTo=id) instead).

To solve this you want to use [`Emoji#id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji?scrollTo=id) for custom emojis specifically or use [`Emoji#identifier`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji?scrollTo=id).

This means you can either do

- `reaction.emoji.id === heEmoji.id`
- `reaction.emoji === heEmoji` ( not 100% safe )
- `reaction.emoji.identifier=== heEmoji.identifier`.

Comment: I changed the emoji lines to
`if (reaction.emoji.id === heEmoji.id)`

however its still not giving out the roles

I tested manually adding the roles, and removing the reaction from the message removes the role. No idea why it wont add though.

Comment: Hmmm, as both use the same code, it should work tho.

Comment: Yeah its stressing me out that it'll remove roles but not add them, the code is exactly the same except for add/remove. I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Can you upload the updated code to something like, https://paste.gg/ so I can have a look over it?

Comment: I've got it uploaded here https://srcb.in/FrEhjbuglw Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `if (reaction.message.channel === channel) {` try `if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel.id) {`. Otherwise, I noticed that Discord is kinda slow on refreshing the Roles ( atleast for me, so it could take 10s or more until you see the Role beeing added ). If everything fails, try to place console.log's to find out where the error happens, like this: https://sourceb.in/9APlU8CfnV

Comment: I copied that code and in the console got https://sourceb.in/hf0BDKP0D7 when clicking the she reaction, so I'm guessing something is wrong or missing in the code somewhere

Comment: Sorry my mistake, `if (reaction.message.channel === channel) {` should be `if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {` as channel is string anyways. https://sourceb.in/gt3i2aYpde

Comment: Nice no problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom emojis for your bot, make sure that the bot is in a server with the custom emoji you want, I suggest making a new server dedicated to this. Next, all you need to do is put a `\` before the emoji. It should then send something like this: `<:emoji_name:0123456>`. You're going to want to simply add that to the definition of your desired variable.

Comment: I have done that - the emojis come up on the embedded post. The issue is that it won't give the role when clicking the emojis