# Discord.js - msg.react is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to do a reactionrole function for my Developing Discord Server.
I got it from [Reaction Roles with Custom emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163962/reaction-roles-with-custom-emojis)  and customized it a bit.I need to write a bit more cuz else it wont be accepted xD. This is my error: TypeError: msg.react is not a function. Here is my code:

```
if(message.content.startsWith("-sendreactionrole")) { try{
   const channel = client.channels.cache.get("922444205303943198")
       const cplusplus = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "C++");
       const csharp = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Csharp");
       const html5 = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "HTML5");
       const java = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Java");
       const javascript = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "JavaScript");
       const python = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Python");
       const scratch = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Scratch");

       const cplusplusemoji = client.emojis.cache.get("922493256598691850");
       const csharpemoji = client.emojis.cache.get("922493255789207622");
       const html5emoji = client.emojis.cache.get("922493480427749458");
       const javaemoji = client.emojis.cache.get("922493255780814928"); 
       const javascriptemoji = client.emojis.cache.get("922493256577724436");
       const pythonemoji = client.emojis.cache.get("922493255613046885");
       const scratchemoji = client.emojis.cache.get("922493480985579540");
       const { MessageReaction } = require("discord.js");
       let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle("Reaction Roles")
       .setDescription(`If you're interested in the coding channels, react to this message with these Icons:\n<:cplusplus:922493256598691850> C++\n<:csharp:922493255789207622> C# (Csharp)\n<:html5:922493480427749458> HTML5 \n<:java:922493255780814928> Java\n<:javascript:922493256577724436> JavaScript/Node.JS\n<:python:922493255613046885> Python\n<:scratch:922493480985579540> Scratch`)
       let msg = message.channel.send(embed);
       msg.react(cplusplusemoji);
       msg.react(csharpemoji);
       msg.react(html5emoji);
       msg.react(javaemoji);
       msg.react(javascriptemoji);
       msg.react(pythonemoji);
       msg.react(scratchemoji);

       client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
           if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
           if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
           if (user.bot) return;
           if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

           if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
               if (reaction.emoji.name === cplusplusrole) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(cplusplus);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === csharpemoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(csharp);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === html5emoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(html5);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === java) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(java);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === javascriptemoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(javascript);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === pythonemoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(python);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === scratchemoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(scratch);
               }
           } else {
               return;
           }
       });

       client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
           if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
           if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
           if (user.bot) return;
           if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

           if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
               if (reaction.emoji.name === cplusplusrole) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(cplusplus);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === csharpemoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(csharp);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === html5emoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(html5);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === java) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(java);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === javascriptemoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(javascript);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === pythonemoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(python);
               }
               if (reaction.emoji.name === scratchemoji) {
                   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(scratch);
               }
           } else {
               return;
           }
       });} catch(err) {console.log(err)}
```

Comment: It's message.react, not msg.react

Comment: `message.channel.send(embed)` returns a promise, so it should be `let msg = await message.channel.send(embed)`